# NullPointerException occur when using contains method on an ArrayList

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm writing this helper method which will be used in another method where several files can be selected. One of these files will be passed as an argument to this helper method. This helper method uses an object from *FileResource* class which is used to read each word or each line of a file through a for each loop. The words from the files work as a key to an initialized *hashmap* and the value to this key is an *ArrayList* which contains the filename as *String*.
In summary, every word in the file is a key to a *hashmap* and the key is mapped to an *ArrayList* containing the file name. This helper method is called several times with different filenames.

the problem is when I use this code, the line "*if(!fileList.contains(file))*" throws a **NullPointerException**. This line checks if the *ArrayList* already contains the *String* or not.

Is there any problem with my algorithm? what causes this problem to occur?

the code is given below:

```
private void addWordsFromFile(File fi){
FileResource f = new FileResource(fi);
String file = fi.getName();
System.out.println(file);
 for(String s : f.words()){
  System.out.println(s);
  ArrayList<String> fileList = myMap.get(s);
  if(!fileList.contains(file)){
    fileList.add(file);
    myMap.put(s, fileList);
    }       
  else{
    break;
    }
}
```

}

[This is the image to this method. It is written in BlueJ environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyats.png)

Answer (score 1):

`myMap.get(s)` returns `NULL`.

Check the condition `if (fileList == null) { ....throw Exception.... }`

or

Use `myMap.getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)`, so if the requested `key` is not found it will assign default value.

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer exception can happen due to myMap.get(s) returning null.
Before putting contains check in if , you can put a null check like

```
  if(null!=fileList){
    if(!fileList.contains(file)){
         fileList.add(file);
         myMap.put(s, fileList);
     } else{
          break;
     }
   }
```